# Craving-clinging leads to volitional actions that can be used for duties. If I let go of craving, how would I do duties to family?

Tags: vipassana

If I let go of craving by doing Vipassana, then according to dependent origination, there would be no clinging. With no clinging, there would be no volitional actions - without these actions, how would I do duties to family members?

Comment: I would say that craving and clinging lead to actions that are compelled, not volotional.

Answer (score 3):

Craving is not required to help your family. You only need compassion(Karuna) and kindness(Metta). Craving only makes you worried and sad.

Comment: Hi Sankha - Is it bhava tanha , if I am doing it because it is “my” family http://daronlarson.blogspot.com/2008/12/three-kinds-of-craving.html?m=1

Comment: Taking anything as 'mine' is ignorance. Bhava Tanha is the  craving for becoming. None of those are required to help family members.

Answer (score 2):

Every condition of dependent origination is ignorant or affected by ignorance. Therefore, when ignorance ends & enlightenment occurs, the only action performed are wise & compassion actions, similar to the actions of the Buddha.

If you continue to do actions because of the idea of "my family" then your vipassana has not been fully successful.

In summary, the Buddha did not teach his noble path was for householders. For householders, the Buddha generally taught the path to 'heaven' rather than the path to Nibbana.

> Monks, these two extremes ought not to be practiced by one who has
>   **gone forth from the household life**. There is devotion to indulgence of sense-pleasures, which is low, coarse, the way of
>   ordinary people, unworthy and unprofitable; and there is devotion to
>   self-mortification, which is painful, unworthy and unprofitable.
>
> Avoiding both these extremes, the Tathagata (The Perfect One)[1] has
>   realized the Middle Path; it gives vision, gives knowledge, and leads
>   to calm, to insight, to enlightenment and to Nibbana.
>
> SN 56.11
>
> ---
>
> The ascetics and brahmans thus ministered to as the Zenith by a
>   householder show their compassion towards him in six ways:
>
> (i) they restrain him from evil,
>
> (ii) they persuade him to do good,
>
> (iii) they love him with a kind heart,
>
> (iv) they make him hear what he > has not heard,
>
> (v) they clarify what he has already heard,
>
> (vi) they point out the path to a **heavenly state**
>
> DN 31